# JQuery table pagination (MySQL + PHP)

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, pagination

I'm trying to create a pagination in my JQuery table using PHP + MySQL + JQuery but I don't know how I can implement it.

That's why I need your help, I need a simple pagination (I don't mind if it's really really simple) I just need it to work, because it's the final step in my first JQuery table.

I'm going to post the URL of my website with the table working (without pagination at the moment, I have more than 500 entries but I only show 20 at the beginning).

URL: [Click Here](http://bdebeauty.es/index.php?option=com_jumi&view=application&fileid=14&Itemid=258)

Script JQuery:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
<script>
  function makeTable(data) {
      var tbl_body = "";
      $.each(data, function () {
          var tbl_row = "";
          $.each(this, function (k, v) {
              tbl_row += "<td>" + v + "</td>";
          })
          tbl_body += "<tr>" + tbl_row + "</tr>";
      })

      return tbl_body;
  }

  function getEmployeeFilterOptions() {
      var opts = [];
      $checkboxes.each(function () {
          if (this.checked) {
              opts.push(this.name);
          }
      });

      return opts;
  }

  function updateEmployees(opts) {
      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "submit.php",
          dataType: 'json',
          cache: false,
          data: {
              filterOpts: opts
          },
          success: function (records) {
              $('#employees tbody').html(makeTable(records));
              // here, after the content is inside DOM/visible we activate the plugin
          }
      });
  }

  var $checkboxes = $("input:checkbox");
  $checkboxes.on("change", function () {
      var opts = getEmployeeFilterOptions();
      updateEmployees(opts);
  });

  $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
      $('#loading').fadeIn("slow");
  }).ajaxStop(function () {
      $('#loading').fadeOut("slow");
  });

  $(window).load(function () {
      updateEmployees();
  });

</script> `
```

And also here is the SQL part with PHP:

```
$sql = $select . $from . $where;

$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute();

$results = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$json = json_encode($results);

echo($json);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to add pagination buttons at the bottom of your table and when they are clicked you call your php sender script with a the page number that was on your button as a parameter.
Then from the PHP script you need to add a LIMIT statement in your mySQL query at the end.
Add

```
LIMIT A,B
```

A is your page number * the number of articles by page.
B is your page number * the number of articles by page + the number of articles by page.

And when you receive the data clear your table before adding new rows.

```
$("#employees tbody").remove();
```

Comment: Thanks Val Hook, I'm going to try this.

Comment: Well I'm glad this helped :)